# Can't create a blank template

Tags: plugin-development, page-template

I want to create a template page that is basically blank, and to which I will add scripts to load an **Angular app** that is used for managing an extra table in my WP database. I created a Page in WP with no content, a Template file (see below) and set the Page to use the template.

The problem is that all of the header and footer info is still present whereas I want a completely empty screen. The calls to these are present in index.php and I'm wondering whether that is the problem and, if so, what I can do about that?

Is there a better way to achieve the same on the admin side using the absolute minimum of php, which is a language I do not (want to) know.

```
<?php /* Template Name: RestoDB */ ?>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Only content</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

When I go to localhost:8000/backend I get all the headers and footers etc.

[image]

Comment: The header/footer will not be included unless you `include()` or `require()` them, or unless you call `get_header()` and `get_footer()`. Your template file doesn't contain those, so I'm a little suspicious as to whether or not it's _actually_ being used as you think. Calls to include the header/footer in `index.php` will not matter so long as your custom template is being used.

Comment: that was my expectation too, which is why I resorted to asking the question.

Comment: Copy that. Might want to have a closer look at your theme to see if it's doing something out of the ordinary, such as attaching the header/footer through a hook or filter instead of via `header.php` and `footer.php`.

Comment: good thinking - I'm using Roots and that seems to rely upon a base.php as well as index. I found the relevant docs and have worked out how to implement the work around